# cmake cross compiling

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

On ubuntu 10.10 64bit I want to compile something with cmake for a 32 bit ubuntu 10.10 system. How can I do that via a shell command in cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CMakeLists.txt add

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m32"
CMAKE_C_FLAGS="-m32"
```

make sure that any libraries you are linking to are compiled for 32 bit.